# nth roots of the polynomial $x^3 =2$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

I have to find the solution of the polynomial x^3 - 2 =0.

Attempt:

$x^3=2$

$x^3=2.1 =2(cos2k\pi+isin2k\pi)$ and $k=0,1,2$

$x=2^{1/3}(cos(\frac{2k\pi}{3})+i sin(\frac{2k\pi}{3}))$

now we will get three roots, when $k=0,1,2$

when $k=0$,

$x=2^{1/3}$..how to find the value...? or $2^{1/2}=1.414....$similarly $2^{1/3}=?$ pls explain

Comment: Is $ x \in \mathbb C $ ?

Comment: $2^{1/3}=\sqrt[3]{2}$...

Comment: we need to find that...

Comment: $2^{1/2}=1.414....$similarly $2^{1/3}=?$

Comment: $2^{1/3} = 1.2599210498948732...$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x^3=2$$

$$x^3=2(\cos2k\pi+i \sin2k\pi)$$ and $$k=0,1,2$$

$$x=\sqrt[3]{2}(\cos(\frac{2k\pi}{3})+i \sin(\frac{2k\pi}{3}))$$

$k=0 \Rightarrow x=\sqrt[3]{2}$

$k=1 \Rightarrow x=\sqrt[3]{2}(-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt3}{2})$

$k=2 \Rightarrow x=\sqrt[3]{2}(-\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt3}{2})$

Answer (score 1):

I think this is easier to see in  the complex exponential form.

Note that for all integer values of $k$:

$e^{2k\pi i}=1$

This allows us to rewrite the original equation as 
$$\begin{align}x^3&=2\\ x^3&=2\times1 \\x^3&=2e^{2k\pi i}\end{align}$$

Now raising each side to the power $\frac{1}{3}$ leaves:

$$\begin{align}x&=\left(2e^{2k\pi i}\right)^{1/3} \\x&=2^{1/3}e^{2k\pi i/3}\end{align}$$

Or in trigonometric form:  $x=2^{1/3}\left(\cos\frac{2k\pi}{3}+i\sin\frac{2k\pi}{3}\right)$

Note you can now substitute integer values for $k$ but you will find that the values for $x$ start to repeat.